# Kafka Console Consumer Error: Failed to Construct Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I am encountering an error while trying to run the Kafka Console Consumer command. When executing the command with the necessary parameters, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR Unknown error when running consumer: (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:830)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:665)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:646)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:66)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:53)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Class io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor cannot be found
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:398)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:480)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:461)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:703)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:422)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:411)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:396)
    ... 8 more
```

**Command Used:**

```
kafka-console-consumer \
    --bootstrap-server pkc-l6wr6.europe-west2.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 \
    --consumer.config /Users/syedashfaq/Developer/Kafka/Confluent-Kafka-CLI/java.config \
    --group testing_group \
    --whitelist "consumer_test1|consumer_test2" \
    --consumer-property "interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor" \
    --consumer-property "partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor" \
    --consumer-property client.id=C1
```

**Steps Taken:**

- Verified the file paths for the Confluent executable file and the monitoring interceptors JAR file, ensuring they are correct.
- Confirmed appropriate file permissions for both files.
- Added the necessary export statements to my ~/.bashrc (or ~/.bash_profile) file and sourced the modified configuration file.
- Checked for conflicting environment variables and ensured there are no conflicting definitions.
- {!} I have verified my topic names, config parameters, consumer group names

**Additional Information:**

- Confluent Platform Version: 3.18.0
- Operating System: macOS (MacBook M2)
- Confluent CLI: Installed and configured correctly

I kindly request your assistance in resolving this issue. If you have any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps that can help me resolve this error and successfully run the Kafka Console Consumer, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your support and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix error by either removing interceptor.classes property

Or ensure the monitoring interceptor jar file is on the command classpath